# how to use border radius only on corners?

Tags: css

I am using `border-radius` to make a curved edge around a link in my site. However, while this works on everything else fine, on my link it curves the entire link around, rather than just the corners. Is there any way to get it to only curve the corners of it?[image: link curving entire thing rather than edges.]

I have tried radius's from 1-50% and it always curves the entire thing, rather than corner.
Thanks if you can help.

Comment: pixel value not percentage

Comment: Ah. Such a simple fix. Thank you :D

Comment: It looks like you've declared an `a{... border-radius:...;}`. This means that on every a tag (link tag), there will be a border radius of the specified amount. If you used `#link-num-1{border-radius: 15px;}` and  `#link-num-2{border-radius: 5px;}` then you might achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Nono, no Border-Radius on all links. Just on the one link.